# setting variable with function's result

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I call the following function with

```
Call GameTimer(FormatDate(objLiveCommentary("DateFirstStarted"), "WithTime"), 
               FormatDate(objLiveCommentary("DateSecondStarted"), "WithTime"), 
               "Soccer")
```

And it prints results as 23, 35, 64, 90. I want to take this result and store it as

```
CurrentGameTime =
```

because I will save CurrentGameTime to my database. How can I do it?

```
Function GameTimer (FirstStarted, SecondStarted, GameType)

If GameType =   "Soccer"    Then
    DateFirstStarted    = DateDiff("n", FirstStarted, FormatDate(NOW(), "WithTime"))
    DateSecondStarted   = DateDiff("n", SecondStarted, FormatDate(NOW(), "WithTime"))

    If DateFirstStarted <= 45 Then
    Response.Write DateFirstStarted
    ElseIf DateFirstStarted <= 45 Then
    DateFirstStarted
    ElseIf DateSecondStarted <= 45 Then
    Response.Write DateSecondStarted + 45
    ElseIf DateFirstStarted <= 45 Then
    DateFirstStarted
    Else 
    Response.Write "90"
    End If  
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I added usage and refactored to use an array of period start times.

Comment: Corrected the bug returning full time between periods.

Comment: I'm honored by your comment on my solution. If you didn't already hear about it; "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob) gave me a lot insight on how to refactor and improve code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the result of your Function you need to set the Functions return value:

```
Function GameTimer(FirstStarted, SecondStarted, GameType)
    ...
    GameTimer = 90
End Function
```

Your *GameTimer* Function should look something like this:

```
Function GameTimer(FirstStarted, SecondStarted, GameType)
    Dim result
    result = 90

    If GameType = "Soccer" Then
        DateFirstStarted = DateDiff("n", FirstStarted, FormatDateTime(Now(), 0))
        DateSecondStarted = DateDiff("n", SecondStarted, FormatDateTime(Now(), 0))

        If DateFirstStarted <= 45 Then
            result = DateFirstStarted
        End If

        If DateSecondStarted <= 45 Then
            result = DateSecondStarted + 45
        End If
    End If

    GameTimer = result
End Function
```

This would work, but it's still not clean code.

First, you should get rid of the *GameType* because what you actually want, is to determine the length of a period:

```
Function GameTimer(FirstStarted, SecondStarted, PeriodInMinutes)
    Dim result
    result = PeriodInMinutes * 2

    DateFirstStarted = DateDiff("n", FirstStarted, FormatDateTime(Now(), 0))
    DateSecondStarted = DateDiff("n", SecondStarted, FormatDateTime(Now(), 0))

    If DateFirstStarted <= PeriodInMinutes Then
        result = DateFirstStarted
    End If

    If DateSecondStarted <= PeriodInMinutes Then
        result = DateSecondStarted + PeriodInMinutes
    End If

    GameTimer = result
End Function
```

**Usage**

```
CurrentGameTime = GameTimer(FormatDateTime(objLiveCommentary("DateFirstStarted"), 0),
    FormatDateTime(objLiveCommentary("DateSecondStarted"), 0),
    45)
```

A next step would be to replace the parameters FirstStarted and SecondStarted by an Array to allow games with thirds and quarters.

---

**Array of period start times**

```
Function GameTimer(Periods, PeriodInMinutes)
    Dim result
    Dim currenttime
    Dim i

    result = 0 '-- preset to zero --'

    For i = 1 To (UBound(Periods))
        currenttime = DateDiff("n", Periods(i), FormatDateTime(Now(), 0))

        If currenttime > 0 Then
            If (currenttime <= PeriodInMinutes * i) Then
                result = currenttime + (PeriodInMinutes * (i - 1))
            Else
                result = PeriodInMinutes * i
            End If
        End If
    Next

    GameTimer = result
End Function
```

**Usage**

```
Dim CurrentGameTime
Dim IceHockeyPeriods(3)

IceHockeyPeriods(1) = "2010-04-15 19:30"
IceHockeyPeriods(2) = "2010-04-15 20:00"
IceHockeyPeriods(3) = "2010-04-15 20:30"

CurrentGameTime = GameTimer(IceHockeyPeriods, 20)
```

**Edit**

Refactored to correct the flaw that between periods the full time is returned.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Can you explain a little bit more about replacing FirstStarted and SecondStarted by an array?

Comment: Also, CurrentGameTime = result or CurrentGameTime = GameTimer?

Comment: This is brilliant Filburt. I love the way you planned and organized it. One last question though. If I am not mistaken, it will print "   result = PeriodInMinutes * UBound(Periods) '-- preset to max game time --'" between two periods. So between period one and period two of a hockey game, the function will print 60. Can you think of a way to fix that flaw?

Comment: @zurna: You are right - this is a bug. I did fix this by reorganizing the Ifs and distinguishing between period time and inter-period time.